# Reading/Writing data via COM Port in VB6

Tags: vb6, serial-port

I am working with a laboratory machine (cobas 6000) to implement LIS using VB6. The machine has a COM port (9 pin).
How can I read the data from machine to my software and write my software data to machine through COM Port?

Answer (score 3):

You should have a look at the MSComm control for VB6.

This allows you to read and write data on a serial port:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa259393(v=vs.60).aspx

An example project is here:

http://www.developerfusion.com/code/195/mscomm-example/

Comment: ok thanks for assistance Matt, Let me have a look at the given link. if required, i will get back to you.